The use of "whether"
Let me show you a sentence below.

At issue is the hotly debated topic of whether coffee is good for you.

In the sentence, How do the word whether work? And Why the of can connect the whether?

I edited your question.  The title should summarise the question.  "I am a beginner" is a bad title for this question.  I removed "I have a question" and I removed "Thank you for reading".  Those are not needed.  I formatted the example as a quote.

You use "whether" to introduce some options.

Tell me whether I should wear trousers or a skirt.

With only one option it implies "...or not".
The meaning is "whether coffee is good for you or coffee is not good for you"

Thank you indeed for your support.
